# Invalid date after conversion 12h -> 24h

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I want to convert AM/PM time to 24h. That should be totally trivial... however I'm standing against a weird issue:

```
let inputDateString = "11:05:45PM"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ssa"
let inputDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(inputDateString) // "Jan 1, 2000, 12:05 PM" ???

if let inputDate = inputDate {
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
    print(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(inputDate))
}
```

1. I thought that maybe it's converting the time using some weird timezone. So I've tried to add `systemLocale` or GB locale, that didn't help.
2. Then I've came up with the idea, that maybe it can't set date previous to 01.01.2000 12:00:00 (what is without sense, because it should work at least from year ~1970). So I've added the day, month etc to move it to 2005 year, but the issue still persists.

You can easily paste this to the Playground with `import Foundation` to test it out.

Why am I getting wrong hour?

-- Edit --

If you change `inputDateString` to any other hour like `"01:05:45PM"`, the `inputDate` would be the same :/ But if you change minutes or seconds, it gets updated accordingly.

Comment: First format should be `hh:mm:ssa`

Comment: 1 Jan 2000 is because you want read a date from no date but time only. It puts default in it.

Comment: @pedrouan That wasn't the question. Anyway, the answer is already below ;).

Comment: I saw it. Just to be clear @Vive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the dateFormat to `"hh:mm:ssa"`, as the lowercase `h` signalizes that the input time is in 12-hour format.

DateFormatter uses the Unicode standard for formatting, so it uses the values found in [the Unicode Documentation](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) (Valid for macOS 10.9 and iOS 7 and newer, as of 08/2016).

An easier-to-use reference can be found on http://nsdateformatter.com.

Comment: The second one is a fantastic reference, thanks for the URL!

Comment: The DateFormatter interprets the format string quite literally. The `a` just tells it, this is the position where the AM/PM information could be found. He still needs to know whether the actual hours input is in 12-hour (`hh`) or 24-hour (`HH`) style.

Answer (score 0):

```
let inputDateString = "11:05:45PM"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ssa" // Here, change the format string to "hh:mm:ssa"
let inputDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(inputDateString) // "Jan 1, 2000, 12:05 PM" ???

if let inputDate = inputDate {
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
    print(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(inputDate))
}
```

Comment: That's the same response as @ast1, posted 20 mins ago and accepted. What's the profit from this answer?